# Adding Index to column in mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

How do I create an index with PHPmyadmin?

I have a database with 5,000 rows of

```
ID | IP | DATE
```

Before added data to this table I made `id` as Primary Key,

The website use this query:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE ip = '$ip'");
```

I read today that indexes can speed up and performance, 
and in my case how do i need to add index to IP column,

I am to phpmyadmin and to actions I see "Add unique index" and "Add index" options,
Im new in this, appreciate your help, thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67710911/2685694 see easy way from PHPMYADMIN

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Click on the icon that says "index" in the row for `ip`. (It's the one with the lightening bolt). Don't choose `primary key` or `unique`. Just index.

Comment: ok selected ip row and clicked that icon, and result:
Your SQL query has been executed successfully

Comment: It's nice when it really is that easy :)

Comment: thanks for fast reply, now i see 2 indexes PRIMARY for ID and ip for ip, do i need to remove the primary of id?

Comment: Nope. I'd say leave it as it can only be useful.

Comment: @JohnConde my database contains 5.7M rows so its not working!

Comment: @Muhammad 5.7 million rows is *not* a lot by any standards

Comment: @JohnConde then what can be the problem, using phpmyAdmin it took too long but at does not show any result.

Comment: SEE EASY WAY FROM PHPMYADMIN: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67710911/2685694

Answer (score 12):

Or you can run a query:

```
ALTER TABLE `users` ADD INDEX `ip` (`ip`)
```

Comment: It's a good idea because sometimes you need to save this queries in order to update other databases. Sometimes queries on PHPMyAdmin simply won't run directly on Mysql as well.