# How to do Indexing of database tables in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, indexing

I want to boost up my database speed each time when new query hit to database table. Can anybody help me out with how indexing works in phpMyAdmin & how to do it??

Answer (score 11):

1. Select a table
2. click on page Structure
3. Below the column section you can found an index section
4. Found the *Create an index on* **x** *columns*
5. Press the button **GO**

Answer (score 6):

you can use [create index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html) statement:

```
create index idx_username on users(username)
```

what actually means: "i want to create index called idx_username on table users on column username"

Answer (score 3):

Set the index from PHPMYADMIN.

I marked the index button in yellow.

[image]