# What is the optimize way of getting latest date from the sql table?

Tags: mysql, sql, max, aggregate

- Hi there, I am looking for the optimal way to get the latest date from the SQL, other than using max(date) in SQL.

***SELECT max(CreatedDate) as createdDate, max(LastModifiedDate) as modifiedDate from user.order;***

Need Suggestion on the solution.

Thanks for the help,

Comment: `CREATE INDEX IX_LastModified ON user.order ( LastModifiedDate ); CREATE INDEX IX_Created ON user.order;` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html

Comment: Well the ideal solution would be to use `MAX()` function itself. Is there any particular reason why you don't want to use `MAX()` ?

Comment: @Salvino The table is huge and aggreation like max is taking around 7 secs to return the result

Comment: @Dai why to use only single index, instead of composite index. Any Reason?

Comment: Well, I would suggest you to first create indexes on the date columns. This is the recommended way when the table is huge. Once you create the indexes try the `max()` query and check. Let us know if it still takes 7 seconds.

Comment: Here's a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36736451/how-to-do-indexing-of-database-tables-in-phpmyadmin/36737248) that shows how to create indexes in `phpmyadmin` just in case.

Comment: @AdityaVyas A composite index won't help in this situation: a composite index is useful only when a query uses two columns `( a, b )` when data in `b` is dependent on `a` - but in this case (where `a` is `CreatedDate` and `b` is `LastModifiedDate`) the two columns are unrelated to each other, hence you need two separate indexes.

Comment: Thanks @Dai for the kind help, will check and update you on that

Comment: Thanks @Salvino for the kind help, will check and update you on that

Comment: SInce you dont use a `group by` clause, you don't need to use `max`  on the entire table. Simply select one item with an `order by CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1`. Since you have two columns, you need two queries, but this still might be faster then max

Comment: @HugoDelsing the order by operation is costly, that too it will hit the db twice

Comment: @HugoDelsing - Partially true.  `ORDER BY..LIMIT` would require two separate queries to simulate the two `MAXs`.  Either way, the existence of two suitable indexes is critical for performance.  And they are equally fast.

Comment: @HugoDelsing - With an index, the `ORDER BY..LIMIT 1` is identical in effort to `MAX()`.  Without an index or with a Limit of more than 1, I agree that `ORDER BY` is costly.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  max(CreatedDate) as createdDate,
        max(LastModifiedDate) as modifiedDate
    from  user.order;
```

Together with these *two* indexes:

```
INDEX(CreatedDate)
INDEX(LastModifiedDate)
```

will be *very* fast.  MySQL's Optimizer is smart enough to do one simple probe into each index.  The `EXPLAIN` will say "Select tables optimized away".  I take that to mean that it got all the data needed during the preparatory step of deciding how to perform the query.

This is one of the very rare cases where MySQL uses more than one index.  And it is *very* effective.

(On a cold system, it took 2ms to do an equivalent query on a 3M-row table.  Furthermore `SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%' confirmed that only 2 rows were touched.)

Answer (score -1):

You have a simple query and there is no more optimal solution.
If your query take too long, that means there is a lot of data in the table.
You can use a Index for your table.

**Index**

Indexes are used to find rows with specific column values quickly. Without an index, MySQL must begin with the first row and then read through the entire table to find the relevant rows. The larger the table, the more this costs.

```
CREATE INDEX YourIndex ON YourTable(column1[,column2,...]);
```

Comment: Long ago, I saw this problem in some other DB.  I was pleasantly surprised with I discovered that MySQL was smart in this area.