# Sorting query performance in PHP+MYSQL

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing

I have a table with huge number of records. When I query from that specific table specially when using **ORDER BY** in query, it takes too much execution time.

How can I optimize this table for **Sorting** & **Searching**?

Here is an example scheme of my table (**jobs**):

```
+---+-----------------+---------------------+--+
| id|        title    |         created_at     |
+---+-----------------+---------------------+--+
| 1 | Web Developer   | 2018-04-12 10:38:00 |  |
| 2 | QA Engineer     | 2018-04-15 11:10:00 |  |
| 3 | Network Admin   | 2018-04-17 11:15:00 |  |
| 4 | System Analyst  | 2018-04-19 11:19:00 |  |
| 5 | UI/UX Developer | 2018-04-20 12:54:00 |  |
+---+-----------------+---------------------+--+
```

I have been searching for a while, I learned that creating INDEX can help improving the performance, can someone please elaborate how the performance can be increased?

Comment: Can you put mysql query code?

Comment: How many rows in the table?

Comment: @RickJames 100 fields almost

Comment: @StormTrooper - Your sample table has 5 rows and 3 columns.  Are you saying the whole table had 100 _columns_?  And how many _rows_?

Comment: @RickJames Around 15 million

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding Index to column in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14419090/adding-index-to-column-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

Add "explain" word before ur query, and check result

```
explain select ....
```

There u can see what u need to improve, then add index on ur search and/or sorting field and run explain query again

Comment: @oles, Can you please tell me how can I add index for sorting and searching??

Answer (score 0):

If you want to earn performance on your request, a way is paginating it. So, you can put a limit (as you want) and specify the page you want to display.

For example `SELECT * FROM your_table LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0`.

I don't know if this answer will help you in your problem but you can try it ;)

Comment: Can you tell me how can I create index on created_at field to sort them DESC ?

Answer (score 0):

Indexes are the databases way to create lookup trees (B-Trees in most cases) to more efficiently sort, filter, and find rows.

> Indexes are used to find rows with specific column values quickly.
>   Without an index, MySQL must begin with the first row and then read
>   through the entire table to find the relevant rows. The larger the
>   table, the more this costs. If the table has an index for the columns
>   in question, MySQL can quickly determine the position to seek to in
>   the middle of the data file without having to look at all the data.
>   This is much faster than reading every row sequentially. 
>   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-indexes.html

You can use [`EXPLAIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html) to help identify how the query is currently running, and identify areas of improvement. It's important to not over-index a table, for reasons probably beyond the scope of this question, so it'd be good to do some research on efficient uses of indexes.

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I add index for sorting and searching?

Comment: The syntax is `CREATE INDEX [index_name] ON [table] ([column]);` However, there are many options for varying types, and the important part is finding one that makes the most sense for your schema and usage. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-index.html

Comment: Can you give me an example for order by DESC on my created_at field? what should be the INDEX query to create?

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE jobs
    ADD INDEX(created_at);
```

(Yes, there is a `CREATE INDEX` syntax that does the equivalent.)

Then, in the query, do

```
ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

However, with 15M rows, it *may* still take a long time.  Will you be filtering (`WHERE`)?  `LIMITing`?

If you really want to return to the user 15M rows -- well, that is a lot of network traffic, and *that* will take a long time.

**MySQL details**

Regardless of the index declaration or version, the `ASC/DESC` in `ORDER BY` will be honored.  However it may require a "filesort" instead of taking advantage of the ordering built into the index's BTree.

In some cases, the `WHERE` or `GROUP BY` is to messy for the Optimizer to make use of any index.  But if it can, then...

(Before MySQL 8.0) While it is possible to declare an index `DESC`, the attribute is ignored.  However, `ORDER BY .. DESC` *is* honored; it scans the data backwards.  This also works for `ORDER BY a DESC, b DESC`, but not if you have a mixture of `ASC` and `DESC` in the `ORDER BY`.

MySQL 8.0 does create DESC indexes; that is, the BTree containing the index is stored 'backwards'.

Comment: I am fetching limited records mostly, but for some cases like statistics or reporting, I am fetching a lot of data, no all of the rows, but a lot

Comment: @StormTrooper - Our answers are vague because we don't have much to work with.  If you would like more detailed help, provide the query, `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Comment: I worked with Mongodb indexing, in Mongodb i use to add index DESC on a timestamp field. So it would sort the records on db level, so in that case when I query record by desending order, it would be a lot faster because the records in db were already sorted. Cant we do something like this with mysql?

Comment: @StormTrooper - MySQL works differently.  I added to my Answer.